# Does Origen.load_target allow initialization options to be augmented?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am using the load_target in my specs testing as so:

```
describe "MBIST Test Module" do

  before :all do
    Origen.app.unload_target!
    Origen.load_target 'prod_a0'
  end
```

And I see the [load_target method accepts an optional options hash](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen.html#load_target-class_method).  However, when I use it like shown below, I do not see the options being applied to the initialization options hash.  Is this expected behavior?

```
describe "MBIST Test Module" do

  before :all do
    Origen.app.unload_target!
    Origen.load_target 'prod_a0', force_import: true
  end
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such options are not passed automatically into the initialization of the DUT model, but rather they are available within the scope of the target file, this is described in this section of the docs - https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/runtime/programming/#Configurable_Targets

If you want them to be available within your DUT initialization, you can simply pass them through:

```
# target/my_dut.rb
MyApp::MyDut.new(options)
```